# Quoting in jQuery.parseJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Via AJAX I recieve encoded json string (json_encode) from php script:

```
response = "{"type":"ok","mess":"File successfuly uploaded"}"
```

and when I'm trying to parse this string `jQuery.parseJSON(response);` js-script fails coz of double quotes at start and in the end.

works fine:

```
jQuery.parseJSON('{"type":"ok","mess":"File successfuly uploaded"}');
```

how to solve this problem?

I always recieve Syntax error: "unexpected_token"

SOLVED: reason was incorrect file encoding. UTF-8 is ok

Comment: try escaping the quotes `"{\"type\"...`

Answer (score 2):

You've already solved the problem. You can't create a JSON string and ignore the standard rules of quote nesting. Either one of these will work:

```
//Denote string by using single quotes
response = '{"type":"ok","mess":"File successfully uploaded"}'
```

OR

```
//Continue to use double quotes and escape the inner quotes
response = "{\"type\":\"ok\",\"mess\":\"File successfully uploaded\"}";
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
response = "{\"type\":\"ok\",\"mess\":\"File successfuly uploaded\"}";
response = "'" + response + "'";
jQuery.parseJSON(response);
```